# Вывод информации на экран Питон

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется код:

```
numbers = map(lambda x: x**2, range(10))
```

если сделать `print(numbers)`, то он выводит

```
map object at 0x7f4af8b07fa0
```

**Вопрос**: 
Как сделать, чтобы он выводил так `[0,1,4,9 итд]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Преобразовать в список:

```
numbers = map(lambda x: x**2, range(10))
print(list(numbers))  # [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо